# Forms for nested structures in yesod

Tags: haskell, yesod

I have the following types:

```
data Cheese = Cheddar Int | Edam String String | Cottage String Int

data Meal = Meal {
      nameOfMeal :: String,
      ... other generic fields
      cheese :: Cheese
}
```

Currently my forms look like:

```
cheddarForm = renderTable $ construct 
             <$> areq textField "Name of meal" Nothing
             <*> areq intField "Cheddar fat" Nothing
      where 
          construct name fat = Meal name (Cheddar fat)
```

I am currently quite happy with the fact, that I need one form for every type of 'cheese' (although I wouldn't certainly mind having a dynamic form..). However, I would really like to get rid of repeating the 'Name of meal' in every form. Can I somehow combine the forms, or do I have to ultimately go for Monadic forms?

Answer (score 3):

Couldn't you just pass around

```
conWithNOM ctr = ctr
    <$> areq textField "Name of meal" Nothing
```

and call that against your other form fields?

```
cheddarForm = renderTable $ conWithNOM construct
    <*> areq intField "Cheddar fat" Nothing
  where 
      construct name fat = Meal name (Cheddar fat)
```